# What's wrong with empty meth, it can' work

Tags: jquery

I use dw and bootstrap style. I make an empty `btn` div to empty the meth I had written but it doesn't work, how can I fix?
When I click id `remove`, it couldn't happen.

this is my body:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form>
                白字
                <input type="text" class="import" id="atk_white" tabindex="1"><br>
                綠字
                <input type="text" class="import" id="atk_green" tabindex="2"><br>
                爆擊率
                <input type="text" class="import" id="cri_rate" placeholder="(%)" tabindex="3"><br>
                爆傷
                <input type="text" class="import" id="cri_dmg" placeholder="(%)" tabindex="4"><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">滿建築<br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="remove" class="btn btn-brown">清空</div>
    <div id="go1" class="btn btn-brown" onclick="myFunction()" tabindex="999"><a>期望值計算</a></div>
```

and script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#remove").click(function(){
          $(".import").empty();
      });
});
```

Comment: What do you want that button to do, exactly? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `val()` instead and pass it an empty string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#remove").click(function(){
          $(".import").val('');
      });
});
```

Comment: That is useful! And it is working now. Could I ask why $().empty(); is wrong or why it can't work? Thanks again lol.

Comment: @Yuting `empty()` removes the child nodes from your selection. If you used it on something like a `<p>` tag, it would remove the text because text is seen as a separate node. But in the case of an `<input>`, the text you enter is its value, which is an attribute and not a separate node. So the `<input>` has no children to `empty()`.